# Unsure about bulk capacitor value and type for custom PCB

Tags: pcb-design, motor, driver, bulk-capacitor

I'm designing a custom PCB (90x90mm approx) which is using an ESP32 module to drive 5 dual channel H-bridge ICs ([DRV8835](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8835.pdf)) which control 9 miniature brushed DC motors (1A stall.)

The datasheet of the DRV8835 says to use an 'appropriate' bulk capacitor on the motor power input, they recommend an electrolytic capacitor close to the IC.

Power to my board is supplied by a 2S1P Li-ion (8.2V maximum.) I won't ever be driving all motors at stall, but I'm not sure on the exact maximum current use and duration. I could potentially be driving a few motors at stall for maybe a second or two (say 5A maximum current draw.)

I'm not really sure what value bulk capacitor to use. Pololu makes a [breakout board](https://www.pololu.com/product/2135/resources#lightbox-picture0J4059;main-pictures) for this IC and they seem to use a 10uF capacitor with a 1 ohm resistor in series for the bulk capacitor.

I suppose my questions are:

1. Roughly, what is the bulk capacitance this board needs?
2. The PCB height is constrained and aluminium capacitors may be too tall. If I were to use ceramic capacitors what additional series resistance should I add and why?
3. If I'm just using a single bulk capacitor at the battery input to the board it will be an inch or two away from some of the H-bridge ICs, is this a problem?
4. What's the worst that could go wrong if the bulk capacitance isn't right?

I'm a mechanical engineer and this is my first PCB design, apologies if these are silly questions.

Comment: The capacitor is filtering out fast current pulses before they hit the transistor/regulator and then the battery, which might cause the voltage regulation to fail.  The resistor is limiting current when the capacitor first charges (during plug in) so that you don't burn up the transistor.  I would leave room for a few capacitors and then test with your motors.  You can use through hole caps and bend the leads so that the height is low.  Otherwise this is going to be hard to calculate without detailed motor specs.